# How do I avoid the hostname Macintosh-2?

Tags: mac-osx, hostname

Whenever I join a network where there are other Macs, I sometimes get the notification:

> This computer's local hostname
>   Macintosh.local is already in use on
>   this network. The name has been
>   changed to 'Macintosh-2.local`.

From then on the result of `hostname` is this changed name. I've tried:

- System Preferences->Sharing->Computer Name.
- `sudo hostname jared-mac`.
- Modified `/etc/hostname`.
- System Preferences->Network->Advanced... ->TCP/IP DHCP Client ID
- System Preferences->Network->Advanced... ->WINS

Is this a known issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://forums.macworld.com/thread/101661

Comment: http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-86633.html

Comment: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1883450

Comment: I actually have encountered the same issue a few times, using a very unique computer name... (I did not try to disable IPV6 like suggested in one of the links above, as it does not really bother me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the two are in sync, but you can alter the hostname by going to:

System Preferences -> Sharing -> Under Computer Name on the right side is an Edit button. **Click the Edit button** and in the new sheet alter your hostname to match your computer name.

Comment: So when your hostname is "jared-mac" it is reverting to "Macintosh-#" - even if the hostname of the other Mac is not the same?

Comment: @Chealion, you are right. You have to press the Edit button which presents a dialog where a completely different value (Macintosh-#.local) is stored.

Comment: @Jared - Sorry I should have made that more clear. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences - Sharing - Computer Name

Comment: Did you try pressing the Edit... button underneath it? Occasionally the Computer Name and Hostname don't match requiring you to adjust it there as well.

Comment: @sweimann, you are almost there. The Edit button next to Computer Name is misleading--it's for editing the local name, not the Computer Name.